# How to load a CSS dynamically in cordova?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, css, cordova

I'm trying to load a CSS dynamically in cordova `onDeviceReady` function using below code.

```
$("<link/>", {
               rel: "stylesheet",
               type: "text/css",
               href: "http://localhost:8080/static/test.css"
            }).appendTo("head");
            if ($("link[href='http://localhost:8080/static/test.css']").length>0){
                alert("localhost css loaded");
            }else{
                alert("localhost css not loaded");
            }
```

The loading of the CSS is not a Problem, I am getting an alert saying "localhost css loaded". But stylesheet don't have any effect, how can I force cordova/clear cache to use imported/loaded css.

Please share your thoughts if we can achieve the same with any other simple solution.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I guess a css included through link will not be picked that way. Try loading the css by a <style> tag. Editing the innerHTML property of that will automatically update the page.

Comment: @Praveen, Sure I will try. What do you mean by editing innerHTML property? Do you mean reload/refresh page once css loaded by a <style> tag?

Comment: I mean try creating a new style element and add your css content to it through the innerHTML

Comment: This seems like a very bad idea. Something that is contrary to mobile development. All assets should already be on the mobile device. Are you sure you want to do this?